# Using Inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, hierarchy

So I just had a job interview and they gave me a list of tasks that they wanted me to work on beforehand. I finished all of the tasks except for one and was wondering if anyone could shed some light on the question.

The question went something like this

1. Create a class called Human, give the class a public property HairColor and a public method Talk() that, when invoked, returns "I am a human."
2. Create another class called child that inherits from Human and overrides the talk method and returns "I am a child."
3. Create a male and female class that override talk and output "I am a Male." and "I am a Female."
4. Change the child and human hierarchy to include male and female appropriately and output the proper string.

I completed tasks 1-3 but was stumped on question 4. I haven't really done much in my past work experience with inheritance and the question seemed kind of vague to me. I explained this to the employer and they seemed ok with it, but didn't tell me how it should have been done. Its been bugging me now and I'm wondering how it is done.

Comment: I don't really think "child" is a *type* of human, it's more of a *state* (ie attribute).

Comment: I think age and sex are attributes of humans and have no place in an inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I'm guessing they wanted you to change it to: Human -> Child -> Male / Female?  I'm with you, that's pretty vague.

Comment: @Blindy That's a choice of design, really.  I do agree that this question is too vague, however.

Comment: Sounds like HR went on the web and paid for interview questions.  The last place I worked did the same thing.

Comment: @MGZero - What is a child anyway? Is it a matter of age, maturity, or intelligence? Is a mentally challenged human of age 30 considered an adult or child? These kind of questions should not cloud the design of a program.

Comment: I would re-think working at this company.

Comment: @Commenters, I doubt the exercise was for an real world use but just as an example to see if the candidate understands the concept of inheritance. I don't think it says anything at all about the company or the interviewers in particular.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram - I know but such a contrived example really irks me. I just imagine a novice developer thinking that programs should be designed this way.

Comment: @ChaosPandion I consider it a matter of age. Do you not agree that inheritence is a perfectly valid way of representing this relationship? Mind you, I did not say this was the BEST way, the best way I think would be Blindy's route. Obviously though, this question is rigged to test your understanding of inheritence and should not be taken as a serious real world design problem.

Comment: I think the interview question was vague on purpose, and they want to try to see how someone would solve it. Or maybe how to behave under unclear conditions. Just change the rules and tell them why the sex nor the age shouldn't matter for the inheritance chain, these are attributes and you would design it that way. Of course that needs some confidence :) It shows you use your head and don't blindly follow stupid constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to fit into their world and desired class hierarchy, which is not particularly indicative of how you might treat a person in a real application, you might have

```
class Human
{
     public string HairColor { get; set; }

     public virtual void Talk()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("I am a human");
     }
}

class Female : Human
{
     public override void Talk()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("I am a woman");
     }
}

class Male : Human
{
     public override void Talk()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("I am a man");
     }
}

class Boy : Male
{
     public override void Talk()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("I am a boy");
     }
}

class Girl : Female
{
     public override void Talk()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("I am a girl");
     }
}
```

This expresses the inheritance hierachy that a boy is a male is a human, and a girl is a female is a human. So you could write any of the below valid statements

```
Human human = new Human();
Human human = new Female();
Human human = new Girl();

Female female = new Female();
Female female = new Girl();

Girl girl = new Girl();
```

And anywhere that takes a `Human` could be passed a `Female` or a `Girl`.

Things such as this would *not* be valid

```
Girl girl = new Human();
Girl girl = new Female();
Female female = new Human();
Female female = new Male();
Female female = new Boy();
```

And naturally, anywhere expecting a `Girl` could not be passed a `Human` or `Female`, and certainly not a `Male` or `Boy`.

In the real world, as commenters have stated, you would typically not use inheritance in this scenario, but instead use properties to differentiate based on age or gender. And, for that matter. If using actual inheritance, you'd probably not opt to use `Male` or `Female`, as those descriptors are hardly unique to humans.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds as though they intend you to demonstrate that you understand the limitations of simple inheritance in this exercise. You *can't* model Humans with both age and sex represented by inheritors in the most simple model of inheritance. Consider the following:

- `Abstract Class Human` inherited by both `Child` and `Adult`;
- `Abstract Class Human` inherited by `Male` and `Female`

It becomes obvious that in this model, a human cannot be both `Child` and `Female` - or any other combination. Therefore the answer is that this simple model is inadequate and instead you should suggest alternative implementations which fulfil the requirements while using the established model as best you can.

I shall repeat what I've found myself saying often:

Objects should not attempt to represent reality. A good object model only need solve the problem at hand.

What I mean by this is that the `Child/Adult` and `Male/Female` exclusivity relationships should be modelled in the most appropriate way that solves the problem at hand. It *doesn't matter* if they aren't representative of reality. In your position I would attempt to suggest a variety of alternatives that would suit varying problems and explain why each is beneficial in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't do this kind of stuff often, but perhaps this would work:

(If nothing else, it gives us a code base to start with)

```
class Human {
  public enum SexType { Unknown, Male, Female };
  public Human() {
    HairColor = Color.Brown;
    Sex = SexType.Unknown;
  }
  public bool IsAdam { get { return true; } }
  public Color HairColor { get; set; }
  public SexType Sex { get; set; }
  public virtual string Talk() {
    switch (Sex) {
      case SexType.Male:
        return "I am a Male.";
      case SexType.Female:
        return "I am a Female.";
      default:
        return "I am a human.";
    }
  }
}

class Male : Human {
  public Male() {
    Sex = SexType.Male;
  }
}

class Female : Human {
  public Female() {
    Sex = SexType.Female;
  }
}

class Child : Human {
  public Child() {
  }
  public override string Talk() {
    switch (Sex) {
     case SexType.Male:
       return "I am a boy.";
     case SexType.Female:
       return "I am a girl.";
     default:
       return "I am a child.";
    }
  }
}
```